# Entity Framework changed to SQL Server Express, how do I change it back to Localdb

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, localdb

I am using EF Code First (.NET 4.5 + VS2012). My project was creating and using LocalDB correctly. I have SQL Server Express also installed on my machine (2008R2). I didn't change any configuration yet it switched to using SQL Server Express.

I have now stopped my SQL Server instance and whenever I try to rebuild the database using `Update-Database` I get the following message:

> *System.Data.ProviderIncompatibleException: An error occurred while
>   getting provider information from the database. This can be caused by
>   Entity Framework using an incorrect connection string. Check the inner
>   exceptions for details and ensure that the connection string is
>   correct. ---> System.Data.ProviderIncompatibleException: The provider
>   did not return a ProviderManifestToken string. --->
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or
>   instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to
>   SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify
>   that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to
>   allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26
>   - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)*

My configuration file has the following EF configuration:

```
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
  <parameters>
    <parameter value="v11.0" />
  </parameters>
</defaultConnectionFactory>
```

Any advice? I'd prefer to be using Localdb rather than SQL Server Express.

Comment: LocalDB is special version of SQL Express.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka Yes, but the database is being created in my SQL Express instance, not my Localdb instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What it turned out to be, for some reason the GUI app.config referenced SqlConnectionFactory not LocalDbConnectionFactory. Fixing this up solved it.